# z3py: Segfault when trying to using set membership

Tags: python, z3, z3py

In Z3Py, I want to express that the value of one (integer) variable must be among a set of valid values. In this case the [E12 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_series_of_preferred_numbers#E12) commonly used for component values in electronics.

I was able to do this with a bunch of Z3 Or clauses (`value == 12 || value == 15 || ...`), but this seems really ugly and inefficient. Each component is my system gets around 80 constraints just to express this one thing. It certainly makes reading unsat error messages hard.

When I instead try to use the `Set` type in Z3Py, it crashes with a segfault. The code below reproduces this.

Is this the right way of using sets for this purpose? Are there other clean ways of doing the same thing?

```py
import z3
import pytest

e12_series = (1.0, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2.2, 2.7, 3.3, 3.9, 4.7, 5.6, 6.8, 8.2, 10.0)

def e_values(start_decade=1, end_decade=6, series=e12_series):
    values = []
    for decade in range(start_decade, end_decade):
        values += [ int(v*10)*10**(decade-1) for v in series ]    

    return values

def value_in(value, valid):
    options = [ value == v for v in valid ]
    return z3.Or(options)

# Values to test with
E12_VALID=[
    120, 18e3,
]
E12_INVALID=[
    119, 19e3,
]

EXAMPLES = []
EXAMPLES += [ (True, v) for v in E12_VALID ]
EXAMPLES += [ (False, v) for v in E12_INVALID ]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('example', EXAMPLES)
def test_bruteforce(example):
    expect_valid, value = example 
    valid_values = e_values()

    s = z3.Solver()
    var = z3.IntVal(value)
    s.add(value_in(var, valid_values))
    satisfied = str(s.check()) == 'sat'
    assert satisfied == expect_valid, s

@pytest.mark.parametrize('example', EXAMPLES)
def test_set(example):
    expect_valid, value = example

    # create a set
    valid_values = e_values()
    e12 = z3.SetSort(z3.IntSort())
    for val in valid_values:
        z3.SetAdd(e12, val)

    s = z3.Solver()
    var = z3.IntVal(value)
    s.add(z3.IsMember(var, e12))
    satisfied = str(s.check()) == 'sat'
    assert satisfied == expect_valid, s
```

Running with `pytest -v setmembers.py`, the output is:

```
platform linux -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-4.4.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.9.0 -- /usr/bin/python
plugins: cov-2.6.1, hypothesis-4.17.0
collected 8 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

setmembers.py::test_bruteforce[example0] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                        [ 12%]
setmembers.py::test_bruteforce[example1] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                        [ 25%]
setmembers.py::test_bruteforce[example2] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                        [ 37%]
setmembers.py::test_bruteforce[example3] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                        [ 50%]
setmembers.py::test_set[example0] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Using `python-z3 4.8.4-2` on Arch Linux

Comment: Replace `e12 = z3.SetSort(z3.IntSort())` with `e12 = z3.Const('e12', z3.SetSort(z3.IntSort()))`; and `z3.SetAdd(e12, val)` with `e12 = z3.SetAdd(e12, val)`. This'll get rid of the segmentation fault. Your tests still fail, but it'll at least let you debug further.